# Problema con el editor de texto djangocms_text_ckeditor

Tags: python, django, cms

Hola estoy trabajando en django-cms usando el editor de texto que trae por defecto djangocms_text_ckeditor, y tengo un problema.

Cuando escribo un plugin de texto, este me formatea este texto de tal manera, que no tengo un salto de linea.

Texto de ejemplo:

```
Quisque semper nunc vitae erat pellentesque, ac placerat arcu consectetur. In venenatis elit ac ultrices convallis. Duis est nisi, tincidunt ac urna sed, cursus blandit lectus. In ullamcorper sit amet ligula ut eleifend. Proin dictumtempor ligula, ac feugiat metus. Sed finibus tortor eu scelerisque scelerisque.Quisque semper nunc vitae erat pellentesque, ac placerat arcu consectetur. In venenatis elit ac ultrices convallis. Duis est nisi, tincidunt ac urna sed, cursus blandit lectus. In ullamcorper sit amet ligula ut eleifend. Proin dictumtempor ligula, ac feugiat metus. Sed finibus tortor eu scelerisque scelerisque.Quisque semper nunc vitae erat pellentesque, ac placerat arcu consectetur. In venenatis elit ac ultrices convallis. Duis est nisi, tincidunt ac urna sed, cursus blandit lectus. In ullamcorper sit amet ligula ut eleifend. Proin dictumtempor ligula, ac feugiat metus. Sed finibus tortor eu scelerisque scelerisque.
```

Asi lo formatea este editor cuando le doy guardar:

```
<p>Quisque&nbsp;semper&nbsp;nunc&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;erat&nbsp;pellentesque,&nbsp;ac&nbsp;placerat&nbsp;arcu&nbsp;consectetur.&nbsp;In&nbsp;venenatis&nbsp;elit&nbsp;ac&nbsp;ultrices&nbsp;convallis.&nbsp;Duis&nbsp;est&nbsp;nisi,&nbsp;tincidunt&nbsp;ac&nbsp;urna&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;cursus&nbsp;blandit&nbsp;lectus.&nbsp;In&nbsp;ullamcorper&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;ligula&nbsp;ut&nbsp;eleifend.&nbsp;Proin&nbsp;dictumtempor&nbsp;ligula,&nbsp;ac&nbsp;feugiat&nbsp;metus.&nbsp;Sed&nbsp;finibus&nbsp;tortor&nbsp;eu&nbsp;scelerisque&nbsp;scelerisque.Quisque&nbsp;semper&nbsp;nunc&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;erat&nbsp;pellentesque,&nbsp;ac&nbsp;placerat&nbsp;arcu&nbsp;consectetur.&nbsp;In&nbsp;venenatis&nbsp;elit&nbsp;ac&nbsp;ultrices&nbsp;convallis.&nbsp;Duis&nbsp;est&nbsp;nisi,&nbsp;tincidunt&nbsp;ac&nbsp;urna&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;cursus&nbsp;blandit&nbsp;lectus.&nbsp;In&nbsp;ullamcorper&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;ligula&nbsp;ut&nbsp;eleifend.&nbsp;Proin&nbsp;dictumtempor&nbsp;ligula,&nbsp;ac&nbsp;feugiat&nbsp;metus.&nbsp;Sed&nbsp;finibus&nbsp;tortor&nbsp;eu&nbsp;scelerisque&nbsp;scelerisque.Quisque&nbsp;semper&nbsp;nunc&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;erat&nbsp;pellentesque,&nbsp;ac&nbsp;placerat&nbsp;arcu&nbsp;consectetur.&nbsp;In&nbsp;venenatis&nbsp;elit&nbsp;ac&nbsp;ultrices&nbsp;convallis.&nbsp;Duis&nbsp;est&nbsp;nisi,&nbsp;tincidunt&nbsp;ac&nbsp;urna&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;cursus&nbsp;blandit&nbsp;lectus.&nbsp;In&nbsp;ullamcorper&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;ligula&nbsp;ut&nbsp;eleifend.&nbsp;Proin&nbsp;dictumtempor&nbsp;ligula,&nbsp;ac&nbsp;feugiat&nbsp;metus.&nbsp;Sed&nbsp;finibus&nbsp;tortor&nbsp;eu&nbsp;scelerisque&nbsp;scelerisque.</p>
```

No tengo idea como solucionar esto, Cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres que te lo muestra así al renderizarlo en el template? Si es así para poder mostrar el campo necesitas usar el tag safe.

Si en tu template pones {{ campo }} te mostrara el html, pero si lo pones como {{ campo|safe }} te renderizara el html de tu editor wysiwyg.

Si tu duda es diferente desarróllala mas, por favor de compartir código de tu form, de tu template, tus views, etc. El codigo siempre es de ayuda.